# Passing prop and using it as a part of a className

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a parent component `<Spinner />` which passes the spinner size `size="sm"` to the child component.
The parent component looks like this:

```
<template>
      <div v-if="isPending">
          <Spinner size="sm" />
          <span> Loading data...</span>
      </div>
</template>
```

The child component looks like this:

```
<template>
      <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-{{ size }}"></span>
</template>
    
<script>
  export default {
       props: ['size']
  }
</script>
```

The child component throws an error because `class="spinner-border spinner-border-{{ size }}"` is not the proper way to add `sm` to `spinner-border-`.
I'm looking for an elegant way to add **only the size suffix** `sm` (**not** adding the whole spinner-border-sm class)

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind your class with `:class` or `v-bind:class` :

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      isPending: true,
    };
  },
})
app.component('Spinner', {
  template: `
    <div class="">
      <span :class="'spinner-border spinner-border-'+size">{{ size }}</span>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['size'],
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-if="isPending">
    <spinner size="sm"></spinner>
    <span> Loading data...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```